# How I can start script after test?

Tags: python, pytest

I have any method with pytest.fixture - autostart before test, I need change this and start after test, how I can change this? Or I should add any option?

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="session")
    def beforescript(self):
        Test.startScriptTest()
```

Thanks for answer!

Comment: Why not call your script in the `tearDown` method?

Comment: You can write it in "SetUp" inbuilt functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="session"))
def after_test(self):
    yield
    Test.afterTestScript()
```

This might work for you, it should start before the test, yield, and only continue after the test is done